# Shapefile To svg to dxf and back to shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, georeferencing, svg, dxf

I need to edit a complex vector polygon layer based on a raster layer. It will be a lot easier for me to do the drawings in an illustration software like Inkscape and then to import it back to QGIS. So I'm planning to export the layers (both the raster and the vector) as svg layers, then to do the edits in Inkscape, and then to save the file as an dxf in Inkscape and finally to import back the dxf to QGIS and converting it back to a shapefile (or geopackage).

The problem obviously is when I import back the dxf to QGIS it's not georeferenced. And if I save the vector layer in QGIS as dxf I can't open it in Inkscape (I don't know why).

Any solutions?

Comment: What versions of Software, we go between qgis (dxf/svg) illustrator for presentation maps.

Comment: @mapperz can i open svg in qgis as a vector layer?

Comment: Inkscape2Symbol plugin but you best route is Illustrator/inkscape to dxf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691541/qgis-how-to-import-svg-or-raster-images-into-quantum-gis

Comment: Thanks @mapperz! I guess my main problem is that i can't open dxf files exported by qgis in Inkscape. I tried also opening it in illustrator and i also got just a blank drawing. How are you exporting your dxf files in qgis?